Distance between the intersections of $y = 2^x$ and $y = \log_2{x}$ on $y = 2 - x$
I've been struggling to answer this question:

Look at the graphs of $y = 2^x$ and $y = \log_2{x}$. Let the line $y = 2 - x$ meet the curves at A and B. Explain why the distance AB is less than $\sqrt{2}$.

Let the $x$ coordinates of A and B be $x_1$ and $x_2$ respectively. Subbing these into $y = 2 - x,$ I found these points: A$(x_1, 2 - x_1)$ & B$(x_2, 2 - x_2).$ The distance between them is thus $\sqrt{2}|x_1 - x_2|.$
When I assume that $\sqrt{2}|x_1 - x_2|< \sqrt{2},$ I find that this must be true: $-1 < x_1 - x_2 < 1.$
I'm unsure how to proceed from here; does anyone know if I did anything wrong or a way to prove this?


Your work is correct, let's complete the proof based on your previous work.
First, monotonicity tells us that $A$ and $B$ is well-defined and unique(Verify). And we know that
$$
2-x_1 = 2^{x_1} \quad 2-x_2 = \log_2(x_2)
$$
Let $t=2-x_2$, we get $t = \log_2(2-t)$,which means $2^t = 2-t$. Because $A$ is unique, $x_1$ is as well unique. It must hold that $t=x_1$. Thus $x_2 = 2-x_1$.
Therefore, to prove $\vert x_1-x_2\vert <1$,we only need to prove $\vert 2x_1 - 2 \vert < 1$, which is equivalent to $1/2 < x_1 < 3/2$. Let $f(x) = 2^x +x -2$, it's obvious that $f$ is strictly increasing and $x_1$ is the unique zero of $f$. Note that
$$
f\left(\dfrac 12\right) = \sqrt 2 - \dfrac 32 < 1.42 - 1.5 < 0
$$
$$
f\left(\dfrac 32\right) = 2\sqrt 2 - \dfrac 12 > 1-0.5 >0
$$
Thus, $1/2 < x_1 < 3/2$, $\blacksquare$.

thank you for the answer! However, I found another way to solve this (refer to the diagram):

$CD=EF$=$\sqrt{2}$
$CD \parallel EF \parallel AB$
Because $CAE$ is concave up and $DBF$ is concave down, then $AB$ must be less than $CD$ and $EF$, and therefore must be less than $\sqrt{2}$
